# Service stopped because "Transport level error"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, windows-services

My Multi Threaded Windows service is frequently getting stopped.
When I check the log it says that 
"A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)"

This is a SQl Error. But why the service is getting stopped because of this error.
Is there any way to over this error, So that the Service wont stop .
My Service wakes up every 3 mins time interval. After the wake when it gets the above error
its terminating/Stopping the service. I don't want the service to stop.

Thanks for your help
Here is my code

---

```
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(GetRecordCount);
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn)) 
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conn.Open();

                    int RecordCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    return TotalRecords;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogTheError(e.Message.ToString());
                return 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: if this is an SQL Error it sounds like the Exception trapping was not captured at the SQLExecption level but at the Exception e level.. but I am just guessing without seeing the actual code implementation

Comment: HI I update my question with the code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the number of TCP connections and number of MS SQL Server open connections.

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```